# How can I reduce duplication in stored procedures?

Tags: sql, postgresql, stored-procedures

As some of my first plpgsql coding I wrote the code below, which to my eye has a lot of repetition. How can I get rid of the duplication?

```
CREATE TABLE devices (
  device SERIAL PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
  fingerprint VARCHAR UNIQUE NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE guests (
  guest SERIAL PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
  uuid CHAR(36) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE vms (
  vm SERIAL PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
  guest SERIAL REFERENCES guests(guest),
  device SERIAL REFERENCES devices(device),
  name VARCHAR NOT NULL  
);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION got_device_guest(fp TEXT, vmuuid CHAR(36), vmname TEXT) RETURNS VOID AS $BODY$
DECLARE
  deviceid INT;
  guestid INT;
BEGIN
  IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM devices WHERE devices.fingerprint = fp) THEN
    INSERT INTO devices(fingerprint) VALUES (fp);
  END IF;
  SELECT device INTO deviceid FROM devices WHERE devices.fingerprint = fp;
  IF NOT (EXISTS(SELECT * FROM guests WHERE guests.uuid = vmuuid)) THEN
    INSERT INTO guests(uuid) VALUES (vmuuid);
  END IF;
  SELECT guest INTO guestid FROM guests WHERE guests.uuid = vmuuid;
  IF NOT (EXISTS(SELECT * FROM vms WHERE vms.guest = guestid AND vms.device=deviceid)) THEN
    INSERT INTO vms(guest, device, name) VALUES (guestid, deviceid, vmname);
  END IF;
END;
$BODY$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: Guess I'm not seeing the duplication.   Each condition being checked represents a different business validation; each insert is for a separate table.  Only thing I see remotely odd is fp is not being evaluated for a null value to start with which will cause an error on insert; but that's by design anyway.

Comment: It can be reduced into plain sql (by moving the IF ... parts into the WHERE clauses), but that won't reduce the complexity. Using the rule system it could even be reduced to a rule on the view on the three tables, but that would be an ugly hack (and rules are not popular)

Answer (score 2):

I don't see repetition here at all. All the statements are inserting data on different tables with different columns, etc. The only way to share those common `if not exists select ...` (and anything else that looks similar on your statements) would be through constructing dynamic SQL which is bad idea on this case.

The reason is a bad idea is that you may expose yourself to SQL Injection attacks and the execution plans for your proc won't be reused, etc. I'd leave this as is.